# How to customize the documents generated by Doxygen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, doxygen, documentation-generation

I am making use of `Doxygen` tool for code documentation for an `iOS` (`Objective-c` based) project.

When the `Doxygen` tool is run for the project it is generating the selected `html` files.
The generated files contains some of the unwanted classes. So how do I customize the documents with `Doxygen`.

It has already been given [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html), but the doubt is how to make use of this with the tool?

Please let us know about it.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a possibility to delete classes from the output. I do this by simply excluding the source files containing the unwanted classes.

Go to the *Expert* tab, choose *Input* and exclude all the files containing your unwanted classes.

[image: Exclude source files]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.. Yes this could  be done i think, but not sure this will satisfy what is needed..

Comment: Why not? Do you run doxygen by yourself or do you simply get the .html files?